# Add a "sleep" in a function when collecting data

Tags: r

I have the following two functions (which are identical apart from the lines):

```
start_dates <- systemtime - 3600*24*(1:10)        
end_dates <- systemtime -  3600*24*(0:9)
```

Where `3600*24*(1:10)` will get the last 10 periods of hourly data and `3600*24*(0:9)` will get the `t-1` periods. The problem is, that I simply cannot apply `3600*24*(1:100)` and get the last 100 periods since the connection gets pinged or timed-out. But I can get for example `3600*24*(11:20)` or the next 10 periods or even further, i.e.)

```
start_dates <- systemtime - 3600*24*(80:100)         
end_dates <- systemtime -  3600*24*(79:99)
```

The data exists on the website so I want to slow the connection down or put a small pause between each request. Just wanting to know how I can add `sys.sleep()` between requests. Maybe

```
3600*24*(1:2) 
sys.sleep()
3600*24*(3:4)
sys.sleep()
etc...
```

Function 1:

```
library(png)
library(IKTrading)
require(PerformanceAnalytics)

library(e1071)
library(caret)
library(class)


###########################################################################

systemtime <- Sys.time()
# Variables
product_id = "ETH-EUR"
granularity = 3600
start_dates <- systemtime - 3600*24*(1:10)         # considering the last 10 days #use 86400*(1:10) when granuality = 300, use 1440*(1:10) when grauality = 60
end_dates <- systemtime -  3600*24*(0:9) #use 86400*(0:9) when granuality = 300

initDate = min(start_dates)

# Function
coinbaseGET <- function (product_id, start, end, granularity) {
  # request url
  req.url <- paste0("https://api.pro.coinbase.com/products/", product_id, "/candles")
  req.url
  # fetching the data ourselves - the return
  res <- httr::GET(url = req.url, 
                   query = list(start = start, end = end, 
                                granularity = granularity))
  res <- as.data.frame(t(matrix(unlist(httr::content(res)), nrow = 6)))
  res[['V1']] <- as.POSIXct(.subset2(res,1L), origin="1970-01-01")
  res
}

# Looping
res <- lapply(seq_along(end_dates), 
              function (k) coinbaseGET(product_id, start_dates[k], end_dates[k], granularity))
res <- do.call(rbind, res)

colnames(res) <- c("date", "low", "high", "open", "close", "volume")
```

Function 2:

```
systemtime <- Sys.time()
# Variables
product_id = "ETH-EUR"
granularity = 3600
start_dates <- systemtime - 3600*24*(80:100)         
end_dates <- systemtime -  3600*24*(79:99) 

initDate = min(start_dates)

# Function
coinbaseGET <- function (product_id, start, end, granularity) {
  # request url
  req.url <- paste0("https://api.pro.coinbase.com/products/", product_id, "/candles")
  req.url
  # fetching the data ourselves - the return
  res <- httr::GET(url = req.url, 
                   query = list(start = start, end = end, 
                                granularity = granularity))
  res <- as.data.frame(t(matrix(unlist(httr::content(res)), nrow = 6)))
  res[['V1']] <- as.POSIXct(.subset2(res,1L), origin="1970-01-01")
  res
}

# Looping
res <- lapply(seq_along(end_dates), 
              function (k) coinbaseGET(product_id, start_dates[k], end_dates[k], granularity))
res <- do.call(rbind, res)

colnames(res) <- c("date", "low", "high", "open", "close", "volume")
```

Comment: I know the function exists, I am just a little unsure on where to put it in the function - in the  `lapply` part?

Comment: I'd think within `lapply` would make the most sense, keeping `coinbaseGET` clean of sleeping. The other option is to offer a `sleep=0` argument to the function, and use the argument when you want it to "play nice" and delay things. Whether that sleep occurs immediately before or after `httr::GET` is up to you (and generally not impactful).